# HttpWebRequest Date Header

Tags: .net, mono, httpwebrequest

I am trying to set the Date Member of System.Net.HttpWebRequest as allowed in .Net 4. in my **Mono** project

My project is definitely .Net 4 and I have the version 4 reference in my project but this Member seems to be missing.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm looking at the history of the mono repository right, the support for the `Date` member [was added to the repository a year ago](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/fb13ef43ce54928ab4307409b571685eced0cc1e). But that commit isn't in the most recent release of mono (2.10.8).

But you should be able to set it using the `Headers` collection:

```
request.Headers["Date"] = date
```

Comment: I just backported that patch to mono-2-10 so soon it should be released in the 2.10.x series.